# Scraping with pyqt interface

Tags: python, pyqt, scrapy

I'm trying to run scrapy spider with a pyqt interface. However, as soon pyqt starts running - scrapy freezes. I can't even get a proper error, it just spits out first few lines of scrapy.
P.s spider runs perfectly on it own

```
import lost_second
import sys
import json
import time 
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


class Form(QtGui.QDialog):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        w =QtGui.QWidget()
        w.resize(250, 150)
        w.move(300, 300)
        self.MyFunction()



    def Parse_me(self,spidername):
        self.spidername = spidername
        configure_logging({'LOG_LEVEL': 'DEBUG'})
        runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

        d = runner.crawl(self.spidername)
        d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run


    def MyFunction(self):
            self.Parse_me(lost_second.MySpider2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

lost_second spider's code:

```
import scrapy
import re
import json
from scrapy.http import Request



class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lost2"
    allowed_domains = ["myurl"]


    def start_requests(self):
        self.video_link = {}
        self.finalone = {}

        with open('list.json', 'r') as z:
            self.links = json.load(z)

        for name in self.links:
            self.video_link[name] ='myurl'+ self.links[name]['link']+'/video'
            request = Request(self.video_link[name],
                              callback = self.video_scrape_parse)
            request.meta['Movie_name'] = name
            yield request

        json.dump(self.finalone, open('video_links.json', 'w'))



    def video_scrape_parse(self,response):
        print('Response url :' + response.url)
        response_name = response.meta['Movie_name']
        print('Response meta name:' + response_name) 
        movie_links = re.findall(r'anotherurl(.*?)mp4', response.body)
        self.x = []
        for item in range(len(movie_links)):
            self.x.append('anotherurl'+str(movie_links[item])+'mp4')
        self.finalone[response_name] =self.x     
        print('Final response response_name:' + response_name)
```

Scrapy logs:

```
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader    middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages    (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console   listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader  middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
 2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages   (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages    (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console   listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2017-04-12 20:38:07 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console  listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
```

Comment: How can you install the following libraries: `lost, lost_second`?

Comment: I got lost.py and lost_second.py with scrapy classes, which being used

Comment: read this:[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example] https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your code can not be tested ... create a minimal example to reproduce the error.

Comment: My apologies. My code have been edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution for my problem is to use threading. My code below:

```
import lost_second
import sys
import json
import time 
import threading
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


##Qtreactor ? Threads?
class CrawlerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CrawlerThread, self).__init__()


    def stop(self):
        try:
             reactor.stop()
        except:
            pass
    def run(self):
        configure_logging({'LOG_LEVEL': 'DEBUG'})
        crun = CrawlerRunner()#get_project_settings?
        crun.crawl(lost_second.MySpider2)
        reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)


class Form(QtGui.QDialog):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        w =QtGui.QWidget()
        w.resize(250, 150)
        w.move(300, 300)
        self.ct = CrawlerThread()
        self.ct.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()


    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```